# How to split drop down column using Extended Menu Extension in Joomla

Tags: joomla, drop-down-menu, joomla1.5, menu

I want to split the drop down columns same like the one on www.whitehouse.gov 
How should I do that ? 
Please help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of mega menus out there, and you don't specifically need a module to acheive it as all they are is a bit of javascript and css. You could use one of the numerous menu systems out there to achieve it:

http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/03/30/mega-drop-down-menus/

or just snoop the code on one of these sites:

http://designm.ag/inspiration/mega-menus/

Of course, if you just want to drop a module in there and forget about it, then go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Its know as MEGA DROP DOWN COLUMNS one good extenstion for joomla is : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/drop-a-tab-menus/10811

website which have mega columns are : 
www.lexus.com
www.whitehouse.gov

Seems that I am used to answering my own questions :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might be the right solution you are looking for.
[A Mega menu for Joomla with many features.](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/drop-a-tab-menus/11578?qh=YTozOntpOjA7czo4OiJtYXhpbWVudSI7aToxO3M6MjoiY2siO2k6MjtzOjExOiJtYXhpbWVudSBjayI7fQ%3D%3D)